# How to get WordPress Username in Array format

Tags: users

I want to create an Autocomplete function in WordPress. I want a search field from where **username** can be searched. I am using following JQuery UI.

```
<label>Users</label>

<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user-name" />

<?php

$get_arr_user = array('John', 'Rogers', 'Paul', 'Amanda', 'Peter');

?>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {                                
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($get_arr_user); ?>;
$( "#user-name" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});

</script>
```

My problem is that I am not able to get the list of **Usernames** in this format - `array('John', 'Rogers', 'Paul', 'Amanda', 'Peter');` How do I get that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but it's possible to achive the same thing with less code using [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
$users = get_users();
$user_names = wp_list_pluck( $users, 'display_name' );
```

`wp_list_pluck()` used that way will get the `display_name` field of all the users in an array without needing to do a loop.

Comment: +1. Also, if less code is the target, then why not: `$user_names = wp_list_pluck( get_users(), 'display_name' );` ;)

Comment: Yes that would work. I just separated them for clarity and consistency with the other answers I was referencing. Though I'd probably leave them separate in my own code, I'm not fond of using functions as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The [`get_users`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function will give you an array of user objects, from which you can extract an array of user names. Like this:

```
$args = array(); // define in case you want not all users but a selection
$users = get_users( $args );
$user_names = array();
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $user_names[] = $user->user_login;
}
```

Now `$user_names` is an array with login names. You can, off course, also use `user_nicename`, `last_name`, or whatever info is available in the [`wp_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object

Answer (score 3):

Look at `get_users()` function.

```
<?php

$users = get_users();

foreach( $users as $user ) {
    // get user names from the object and add them to the array
    $get_arr_user[] = $user->display_name;
}
```

And you'll get the array similar to following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Doe
    [1] => Jane Doe
    [2] => Baby Doe
)
```

I'm pretty sure you'll want to exclude admins, order names and so on. So, look at the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to find out more `get_users()` arguments.